# How do I delete multiple records from an AWS Amplify GraphQL API?

Tags: aws-amplify

I've made a GraphQL API in an AWS Amplify React Native app. The API contains the model `Transaction`. AWS Amplify provides CRUD operations out of the box, and I can delete a single transaction no problem.

However, I would like to delete all transactions that meet certain criteria. How do I delete multiple transactions using this stack (AWS Amplify + GraphQL API, React Native)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send 1 request with batch delete mutation.

using `listTransaction` to get filtered transactions.

```
const txnMutation: any = transactions.map((txn, i) => {
  return `mutation${i}: deleteTransaction(input: {id: "${txn.id}"}) { id }`;
});

await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(`
  mutation batchMutation {
    ${txnMutation}
  }
`)
);
```

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify";
```

Comment: Is this just deleting them one by one, synchronously, in a loop? I would like to delete them all at once for a fast operation. I may be deleting many transactions.

Comment: um no, notice how I am calling GraphQL API only once with one long query string that contains all mutation.

Comment: I think I see now. I haven't created any custom resolvers on the backend. I'm new to GraphQL also, but my understanding is that multiple mutations run in series, and multiple queries in parallel. This will fire off multiple delete mutations in one shot from the front end to the backend, but the backend will execute them in series. If I wanted to truly delete them from the backing DynamoDB instance all at once I would need some sort of custom resolver with a DynamoDB DELETE statement, or whatever that looks like in NoSQL land.

Comment: mhm, that seems interesting. If you found any solutions, please add here as an answer.

Comment: I think your answer is acceptable for my use case, but not quite what the spirit of the question intended. But, this is Stack Overflow, and literal is what counts, not spirit. If I need to continue to optimize I will dig further and post the answer here. But today I will go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How to do the same in the node js?