# How can i perform batch update in graphQl

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have a user schema and have a update mutation

```
mutation MyMutation {
  updateUser(input: {Order: 47, id: "981f3cb8-a369-4f0f-8d3d-28d159a3eace"}) {
    firstname
      id
  }
}
```

Now i have to update multiple list of id with their respective list of order

```
mutation MyMutation($id: [String!] =  ["981f3cb8-a369-4f0f-8d3d-28d159a3eace","0b2cb7d2-8dd9-4b11-846c-6370d003f6f9"], $Order: [Int] = 
    [47,48]) {
  updateUser(input: {id: $id, Order: $Order}) {
    firstname
  }
}
```

But i'm getting below error in console

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateUser": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "updateUser"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Value for field '$[key][id][S]' must be text."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You'll need to implement a mutation on your GraphQL server schema that supports taking an array of input values and batch the update server side. GraphQL can't do the batching on its own with atomic mutations. The only way would be to do it in code, but it would make N network requests where N is the number of updates you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete multiple records from an AWS Amplify GraphQL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966749/how-do-i-delete-multiple-records-from-an-aws-amplify-graphql-api)

Comment: @LuckyTuvshee I want to know how do i update multiple records at once from GraphQl API

Comment: @prachi, update/delete are mutations. It's same. You can send 1 request with all of your mutations.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use a For Loop

```
  async function update(e) {
    for (const item of array) {
      try {
          await API.graphql({
            query: createImage,
            variables: {
              input: {
                id: id,                  },
            },
            authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      } 
    }
  }
```

Option Two, create a custom batch resolver:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html
2. https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/examples-and-solutions/#batch-put-custom-resolver